# Create ML always "converged early at 10 iterations"

Tags: createml

I'm trying to train object detection model with dataset about 100k images, for recognise 7-segment digits (about 10k 100x100 grayscale images per digit) and Create ML stops training with the same result "converged early at 10 iterations", regardless of the accuracy and quality of the data (I started with a dataset of 20k images).

My last try:

- Training Accuracy 68,4%
- Validation Accuracy 68,2%

[Training process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeuEw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - don't try to use Create ML for training models))
I ran the same training on google colab using [this turicreate template](https://colab.research.google.com/github/skafos/colab-example-models/blob/master/ImageClassification/dogs_and_cats.ipynb)
and got 94% accuracy without interruptions at 50 iterations.